# Nginx Rewrite URL Question

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, nginx

I would like to know how I can achieve the following using the nginx rewrite module, I do not have much experience with regex.

I would like to redirect a URL from

www.example.com/foo/1/bar/2/

rewrite to:

www.example.com:9000/foo/1/bar/2/

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com;
  rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://www.example.com:9000$1 redirect;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to do this without the "redirect" option so the redirect is internal.